# How to open bookmarks automatically in Jasper Report PDF export?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext, bookmarks, export-to-pdf

When a PDF is exported from Crystal Reports, the bookmarks panel shows by default when the PDF is opened; however, when using JasperReports, the bookmark panel is not opened by default and has to be opened manually.

How can JasperReports export a PDF that opens with bookmarks shown by default?

Comment: I don't agree with close votes on this question, it's not too broad (see answer), it's not a debug my code question, nor is it documented in jasper-report hence it does not need mcve (what would the attempt be if it's not documented?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFIK there is no [configuration](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html) in jasper-report to set view preference (page mode). My only solution would be to post elaborate the pdf with itext (library used to export to pdf, already in classpath)

## Example

We will export jasper as a PDF to a memory stream (`ByteArrayOutputStream`) then use itext's `PdfStamper` to add viewer preferences [`PageModeUseOutlines`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html#PageModeUseOutlines)<sup>1</sup>

```
//Get the JasperPrint object (exact code to achieve this intentional left out since command depends on application)
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(...); 

//Export to pdf into a memory stream
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
ByteArrayOutputStream memoryStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(memoryStream));
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
        
//Use stamper to set viewer prederence 
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(memoryStream.toByteArray()));
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream("my.pdf"));          
pdfStamper.getWriter().setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageModeUseOutlines);
pdfStamper.close();
pdfReader.close();
```

<sup>1. Link is to itext5 api, but note that jasper-reports actually uses a special version of itext 2.1.7 see maven dependence for more information</sup>